# Location Obfusication and Email/remote login

Tags: email, privacy, ip, obfuscation

Would it be possible for a user of a 3rd party VNC software package and email client to obfusicate/spoof their location, so that an employer would be unable to determine the location from which the user is working remotely?  Could one potentially set up a home server to pass connections through - so as to appear to be operating from home?

Comment: No need for any special software, only need to have a VPN to their home network from that that white sand beach. The dude that offloaded his work to a Chinese company should have done that and would never have been caught.

Comment: Which dude? I like the sound of a white sand beach!

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/01/16/developer_oursources_job_china/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, there are a variety of ways to achieve this, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

A basic example would be that a user could set-up Team viewer on their home PC, then connect to it from anywhere in the world.  they could then use VNC into the office over the Team Viewer connection and appear (from an IP address perspective) to be coming from home.

Comment: Thank you Rory, Team Viewer would be an ideal platform to start this with. What would you suggest for the second link in this chain; a second VNC?